# Prove p is prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p>1$. If for all nonzero integers $n, ~ p$ divides $n$ or gcd($p,n$)=$1$ then $p$ is prime.

I did not understand the proof I read in my text book:
Let $a$ be a positive divisor of $p$.  Then $p = ab$ for some positive integer $b$.
The gcd($p$,$a$)=$a$ and hence if $a$ is not equal to $p$ then the condition implies that $a = 1$.  It follows that $p$ is prime.

I understand gcd($p$,$a$) = $a$ and that if we show that  $a = 1$ or $a = p$ then $p$ is prime. I do not understand how the statement after the word "hence" in the proof follows from the prior assumptions.

Comment: Did you understand $(a,p)=a$, ok? Now, If a=p, finish. But if $a\neq p$, the hypothesis implies $a=(a,b)=1$ and also finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption, one of the following is true:

- $p$ divides $a$
- $\gcd(p,a)=1$.

I'll begin from the step $\gcd(p,a)=a$. If $a \neq p$, $p$ cannot divide $a$. For otherwise, $a=pc$ for some integer $c$. So $p=ab=pcb$, which implies $cb=1$. Hence $c=1$ and $b=1$ (they cannot be $-1$ for both $p$ and $a$ are positive), and thus $p=ab=a$.

Thus $p$ doesn't divide $a$, so the second condition must be true: $\gcd(p,a)=1$. Since you already have $\gcd(p,a)=a$, this implies $a=1$.

Hence either $a=p$, or $a\neq p$ and $a=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from your first line. $p$ can not divide $a$ because if $p=a\cdot b$ then $|a|\leq |p|$ so we must have $\gcd(p,a)=1.$